# What are usage examples for NSFileProviderExtension in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

It seems like the `NSFileProviderExtension` inherits from `NSObject`.
The apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileproviderextension) does not have any usage examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: their wwdc video does not help me at all, it is more like talking about concept more than a product

Comment: You can check how NextCloud does it https://github.com/nextcloud/ios/blob/master/File%20Provider%20Extension/FileProviderExtension.swift. You can also search for the class name in GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider

> If your app is primarily focused on storing and managing user documents, you can implement a File Provider extension to give users access to their content while they're using other apps.
> Your file provider provides access to files stored on your server.
> The File Provider extension:
>
> - Creates placeholders for remote files that you download only as needed.
> - Intercepts coordinated reads from the host app, so that the file can be downloaded or updated from the remote server before the read occurs.
> - Triggers a notification after coordinated writes from the host app, so that the extension can upload the changes to the remote server as needed.
> - Enumerates the stored documents and folders.
> - Executes actions—such as importing, moving, renaming, or deleting items—on the stored documents and folders.